# Unable to Update XAML TextBlock Text Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock in XAML that's bound to a property called EditsWarning:

```
<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding EditsWarning, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{DynamicResource Esri_TextBlockRegular}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,5" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```

The Definition for the EditsWarning Property is here:

```
public string EditsWarning
{
    get { return editsWarningMessage; }

    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref editsWarningMessage, value, () => this.EditsWarning);
    }
}
```

The EditsWarning Property is set to an instance of a class like this:

```
        editsWarning = new OutstandingEditsTextBlock();
        editsWarningMessage = editsWarning.EditsWarningMessage.ToString();
```

And the OutstandingEditsTextBlock class is here, and implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
internal class OutstandingEditsTextBlock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string editsWarning;

    public OutstandingEditsTextBlock()
    {
        if (Project.Current.HasEdits)
        {
            this.editsWarning = "This session/version has outstanding edits.";
        }
        else
        {
            this.editsWarning = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string EditsWarningMessage
    {
        get { return this.editsWarning; }

        set
        {
            this.editsWarning = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("EditsWarningMessage");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I noticed that I can get it to display either value, however, I can never get it to update in the same debugging session. In fact, it looks like the setter for the public property is never hit.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you subscribe to `OutstandingEditsTextBlock.PropertyChanged` how would `EditsWarning` ever get updated? Your question is missing the [mcve] that's required for a useful answer to be provided, but it sounds like you simply haven't implemented your properties correctly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I thought this subscribed me to the property:             `this.OnPropertyChanged("EditsWarningMessage");`

Comment: A call to `OnPropertyChanged()` doesn't subscribe to the event. It _raises_ the event. Even if it did subscribe to the event, it would be in the wrong place. You need for the code that assigns the `EditsWarning` property to subscribe to the event, and then in the event handler, update the `EditsWarning` property whenever it changes.